# Unable to get blogger comments API v3

Tags: .net, api, blogger, google-api-dotnet-client, google-blogger-api

I'm trying to get blogger post comments but getting null even though there are comments on the post.

https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/2399953/posts/7706273476706534553/comments?key=API-KEY

Code

```
Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer service = new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer();
service.ApiKey = "API-KEY";

BloggerService blogger = new BloggerService(service);

var blogQuery = blogger.Blogs.GetByUrl("http://buzz.blogger.com/");
var blog = blogQuery.Execute();

PostsResource.ListRequest query = blogger.Posts.List(blog.Id);
query.MaxResults = 500;

PostList result = query.Execute();

foreach (Post post in result.Items)
{
    CommentsResource.ListRequest commentsQuery = blogger.Comments.List(blog.Id, post.Id);
    commentsQuery.MaxResults = 500;
    CommentList comments = commentsQuery.Execute();
    post.Replies.Items = comments.Items;
}
```

Comment: I,m getting the same problem. I only got success in playground using OAuth 2.0 https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/comments/get?apix=true

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a blogger setting, which was preventing comments from loading.
In the settings go to website feed and activate the complete version. eureka
[image]